# Make sure the results are displayed the other way around (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am using [Lens Studio](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/guides/scripting/scripting-overview/) from Snapchat.

Right now these are the results it get:

- 01:38:03 Tap: 5
  01:38:03    Tap: 4
  01:38:04    Tap: 3
  01:38:05    Tap: 2
  01:38:06 Tap: 1

If the user tap one more time it changes to 01:38:03 to Tap: 6

How can i make sure it is displayed as following:

- 01:38:03 Tap: 1
  01:38:03    Tap: 2
  01:38:04    Tap: 3
  01:38:05    Tap: 4
  01:38:06 Tap: 5

var tap = 0;

```
function onTapped (eventData)

{ 

    tap++;

   var tapAmount = "Tap: "+ tap;

 print(tapAmount)    

//@input Component.Label label1

script.label1.text = tapAmount;

}

var event = script.createEvent("TapEvent");

event.bind(onTapped);
```

My solution was to check how many times the function runned but then i get the same problem...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `print(tapAmount)` you printing to the printer?

Comment: @Andy that’s certainly what the `print` function does in JS anyways. (But you knew that.) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

Comment: @Andy print(tapAmount) is showing it in the console. With the results mention here above.

Comment: @job, no `console.log(tapAmount)` would do that.

Comment: What is `script`, and what is `script.label1`?

Comment: I'm not sure why your `tapAmount` output is decrementing when your code is clearly incrementing...

Comment: @Andy Oh well i am using Lens Studio from Snapchat and it works xD

Comment: @Nate i am using Lens Studio from Snapchat